# IronPython: how could I make VS2008 create IronPython project?

Tags: visual-studio, ironpython

As title described, what things I need to install to enable VS2008 to create IronPython project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this web page](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsxteam/archive/2007/12/14/IronPython-Studio-for-VS-2008-Shell-released.aspx)? (contains details about the IronPython VS shell extension).